# Neo4j add nodes only on merge create

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher that looks like the following

```
MERGE (col)-[:CONNECTS]->(o)
ON CREATE SET col.name = "SOME NAME"
```

Now I want to add the following node and relationship only if the merge creates (not matches):

```
CREATE (o)-[:NEEDS]->(p:anode)
```

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in conditional creation right now in Cypher, I guess it will be added to upcoming versions.

For now you can do a little trick, when creating you set a property on the relationship that will tell it is a new creation, you then do a foreach/case on this property, create the other relationship and remove the property.

Code explains better than words :

```
MERGE (col)-[r:CONNECTS]->(o)
ON CREATE SET col.name = "SOME NAME", r.new = 1
FOREACH (x IN CASE WHEN r.new = 1 THEN [1] ELSE [] | 
                         CREATE (o)-[:NEEDS]->(p:anode) 
        )
REMOVE r.new
```